# Enumerated Directories Name Substring GroupBy Issue

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a lookup from a set of enumerated directories using the `GroupBy` function. I have part of the solution, but can't seem to figure out the rest.

The directories are in a format where the letters of Substring(3,6) are used as the main category and Substring(0,2) will be used as a subcategory.

```
IList<string> sliceSteppingList = mainFolder
    .EnumerateDirectories("?x??0?0*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .ToList();
```

This yields part of the solution, where the output is a sorted list and uses the categories like I wanted, but it has the entire folder name as under the groups, which is not what I want.

The folder names are in this format:

`1x6A0A0
1x6C0C0
3x8A0A0
3x8B0B0
3x8C0C0
5x8A0A0
1x6A0A0SS0
1x6A0A0SS1
1x6A0A0SS2`

What I want it a lookup that has a dictionary or lookup something like this

`-A0
  +1x6
  +5x8
-B0
  +3x8
-C0
  +1x6
  +3x8`

The part with the `SSx` is would be considered a selection after the main and subcategories are chosen, but I'm not sure what to do with that part yet.

Comment: You say that "*the letters of Substring(3,6) are used as the main category*", yet none but the last three have enough characters to generate a 6 character string starting at index 3. And even if they did, your example only shows 2 characters for the main category. Also, where do the `-` and `+` signs come from? do you want those added to the strings?

Comment: Also, given the input, the output looks very incomplete. What happened to all the other values? Shouldn't `A0` also have 1 `'3x8'` and 3 `'1x6'` entries?

Comment: that should have been Substring(3,4) because I wanted the A0A0 or B0B0 parts of the directory name..

Comment: Ah, ok. Updated answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question and sample output, you are looking for a `GroupBy` like this:

```
var sliceSteppingList = mainFolder
    .EnumerateDirectories("?x??0?0*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(dirInfo => dirInfo.Name)
    .GroupBy(dirName => dirName.Substring(3, 4), dirName => dirName.Substring(0, 3))
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key);
```

Here's an example of a way to display the output:

```
foreach (var item in sliceSteppingList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"-{item.Key}");

    foreach (var subDir in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" +{subDir}");
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you much!
What do I need to do so the subDirs are sorted and it removes any diplicates?